# Can't capture output into variable in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, output

Having trouble with `redis-cli`. I wanna check if the connection to `redis` is refused (server down), through BASH.

Simple test

```
#!/bin/bash
test=$(redis-cli exit) #exit out of the "not connected console"
if [[ -z $test ]] ; then
    echo "I'm empty :("
fi
```

I would expect `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused` to be stored in $test, but this text is output to the console instead.

I'm not sure whats going on. Anyone have any ideas?

(Ubuntu 14.04.1)

Comment: Note that `if [[ -z $test ]]` will almost certainly expand to `if [[ -z  ]]` when `$test` becomes empty, which seems likely to break the conditional. To protect against this, simply put the variable in quotes: `if [[ -z "$test" ]] ; then`.

Comment: I actually think that newer versions of bash handle that. Seems to work in my tests anyway.

Comment: Well then, good for you. :-) I tend to like the additional safety net, if nothing else to preserve my sanity when looking at the code later...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's because the error message is being sent to the STDERR stream (file descriptor 2), not STDOUT (file descriptor 1) which you are capturing with command substitution `$()`.

Just focusing on getting the string, either on STDOUT or STDERR:

```
test="$(redis-cli exit 2>&1)"
```

in that case the `[ -z "$test" ]` test will result in false positives as the error message will be stored in the variable. Instead you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
test="$(redis-cli exit 2>/dev/null)"
if [[ -z $test ]] ; then
    echo "I'm empty :("
fi
```

Also i think, this should get what you want given the exit status is trivial:

```
if redis-cli exit &>/dev/null; then
    echo 'Succeeded!!'
else
    echo 'Failed!!'
fi
```

Comment: Ah, of course. It's an error! :)

Comment: Also, it's asking for trouble (if only a little bit) to use the name of a built-in command (and executable) - "test" for a variable name, so just testing the exit status as in the second solution is better for that reason too.